# Как поместить ResultSet или List в tableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Не понимаю технологию помещения данных в `tableView`.

Сперва устанавливаем значение для каждой ячейки `TableColumn.setCellValueFactory`, потом только помещаем данные в `tableView.setItems`.

Если есть возможность покажите на примере.

Answer (score 1):

`TableColumn.setCellValueFactory` - не устанавливает значения для каждой ячейки, оно определяет какие данные будут храниться в ячейках столбца, а затем выводит их.

Ниже пример с подробными комментариями:

```
// Создаём данные, которые будут храниться в таблице
// Список data будет состоять из объектов класса Person
// Каждый объект класса Person будет представлять строку в таблице
ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new Person("Johannes", "Kepler"),
    new Person("Michael", "Faraday"),
    new Person("Daniel", "Bernoulli"),
);

TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>(); // Создаём таблицу

// Задаём столбцы таблицы
TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name"); 
// Указываем какой контент будет хранить данный столбец 
// поле firstName типа String из объекта класса Person
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

table.setItems(data); // связываем данные и таблицу
table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol); // добавляем столбцы

class Person {
    private SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private SimpleStringProperty lastName;

    private Person(String fName, String lName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }
}
```

В результате будет таблица:

```
First Name | Second Name
------------------------
Johannes   | Kepler
Michael    | Faraday
Daniel     | Bernoulli
```